# Broadcom Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter and Motorola HX550 Headset Popping Noise

Tags: windows-8, audio, bluetooth

I have the Medialink Bluetooth 4.0 adapter and a Motorala HX550 headset. I'm on Windows 8 x64. When using my bluetooth adapter paired with a headset, I get a random clicking/popping sound every so often. It doesn't matter how close I am to the dongle, it always does it. I've tried other headsets and they do it as well.

I've had Medialink send me a new adapter and I still get the issue. I've tried the latest Widcomm software as well as the bluetooth stack built into windows 8. I get the sound no matter what.

The only time I didn't get it was with a bluetooth 2.0 adapter that used the Toshiba bluetooth stack.

I'm out of things to try and hope someone knows something that can help. Any help is appreciated.

I want to use the Medialink adapter because I wanted bluetooth 4.0 for other things.

Thanks!